X-axis range changing issue after chart rotation in MPAndroidChart
I made a chart with MPAndroidChart in Android like this.

fig. 1 - This chart is zoomed in and moved all the way to the right. Remember this x range.
And set the optiona below in AndroidManifest.xml so that the chart rotates when the device rotates.
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
...

After that when device rotates to display the chart in landscape mode, the x-axis range changes like this.

fig. 2 - X-axis range is different with fig.1
This is an issue I would like to solve to improve the UX. I think it's because ViewPortHandler of MPAndroidChart doesn't recalculate the values ​​after rotation. I checked the log in Chart.onDraw() as follows and found that the mTransX value shows the same value even after rotation.
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // super.onDraw(canvas);
    Log.e("asdf", "mTransX: " + mViewPortHandler.getTransX());

How can I recalculate mTransX values ​​for landscape mode? I don't know the formula. Or is there another way to solve this issue?
